# How to sort json Object in typescript

Tags: json, angular, sorting

I want to sort a json object in my angular application.

this json object looks like this:

```
{"9 - ABCDEF":{"isSucceeded":true},
"18 - Remote Software Update":{"isSucceeded":true,},
"4 - n.a."{"isSucceeded":true,}}
```

I just sort this json object like this:

```
{"4 - ABCDEF":{"isSucceeded":true},
"9 - Remote Software Update":{"isSucceeded":true,},
"18 - n.a."{"isSucceeded":true,}}
```

Does anybody know some solutions? 
I have heard with underscore.js
Can anybody give me some examples?

Comment: It doesn't look like "sorting" to me. The input one has keys: `"9 - ABCDEF",
"18 - Remote Software Update", "4 - n.a."`, the expected output has keys: `"4 - ABCDEF", "9 - Remote Software Update", "18 - n.a."`. A clarification would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

Using `forEach` :

```js
const object = {
   "18 - n.a.": {"isSucceeded":true,},
   "4 - ABCDEF": {"isSucceeded":true},
   "9 - Remote Software Update": {"isSucceeded":true,},
};
const ordered = {};
const firstNumber = str => parseInt(str.split(' -')[0].trim());
Object.keys(object)
.sort((a, b) => firstNumber(a) > firstNumber(b) ? 1 : -1)
.forEach(function(key) {
   ordered[key] = object[key];
});

console.log(ordered);
```

using the `reduce` function :

```js
const object = {
   "18 - n.a.": {"isSucceeded":true,},
   "4 - ABCDEF": {"isSucceeded":true},
   "9 - Remote Software Update": {"isSucceeded":true,},
};
const firstNumber = str => parseInt(str.split(' -')[0].trim());
const ordered = Object.keys(object)
.sort((a, b) => firstNumber(a) > firstNumber(b) ? 1 : -1)
.reduce((acc, key) => {
   acc[key] = object[key];
   return acc;
}, {});

console.log(ordered);
```